# in karma/mocha test 'before(angular.mock.module('app'));' throw error and `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));` work why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

so I start to use karma/mocha lib to test webpack/angular app

and when I write 
`before(angular.mock.module('app'));` it throw error

```
FAILED timer factory "before all" hook: workFn
debug.html:38 TypeError: Cannot read property '$injector' of null
at Context.workFn (base/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2653:22)
```

and when using `beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));` it work fine.

why??

I think I should init the module one not every test

the code:

```
describe('timer factory', function () {

  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  it('should exist',inject(function (Timer) {
    timer = new Timer();
    should.exist(timer);
  }));
});
```

Comment: i thik, will be step for process, 
so beforeEach could be loaded at first initializacion of test, and before at second, so angular will be required

Comment: here same quesrtion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418580/what-is-the-difference-between-before-and-beforeeach

Comment: that is nice qustion/answer but I know the diffrent between `before` and `beforeEach` . I just not understand way before fail