# Sinon Error "Attempted to wrap ... which is already wrapped" on Multiple Files

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js, sinon, stub

I have multiple files that use sinon to stub the same method `Utils.getTimestamp`.

When running the tests files, one at a time all tests pass.
When running the tests files at once, the tests fail with: TypeError: "Attempted to wrap getTimestamp which is already wrapped"

In both files, I have the describe blocks with a before and after blocks

In the Before block, I stub the method like: 
getTimestampStub= sinon.stub(Utils, 'getTimestamp')
                .returns(myTimestamp);

In the After block I restore the method like: 
getTimestampStub.restore();

I tried this according to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36075457/6584537

Sample files:

**FILE 1**

```
describe("First Stub", () => {
    let getTimestampStub;
    before(() => {
        getTimestampStub= sinon.stub(Utils, 'getTimestamp') .returns("SOME_TIMESTAMP");
    });

    it("Should run some code that uses getTimestamp", () => {
        // Some code that in the process uses `Utils.getTimestamp`
    });
    after(() => {
        getTimestampStub.restore();
    });
});
```

**FILE 2**

```
describe("Second Stub", () => {
    let getTimestampStub;
    before(() => {
        getTimestampStub= sinon.stub(Utils, 'getTimestamp') .returns("SOME_TIMESTAMP");
    });

    it("Should run some OTHER code that uses getTimestamp", () => {
        // Some code that in the process uses `Utils.getTimestamp`
    });

    after(() => {
        getTimestampStub.restore();
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sinon error Attempted to wrap function which is already wrapped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36074631/sinon-error-attempted-to-wrap-function-which-is-already-wrapped)

Answer (score 2):

When Mocha runs multiple files, it runs **all the before blocks** first. This is true for 1 file or for multiple ones.

The error then is because I was trying to stub the same method before it had a chance to be restored. Something like this:

before()

it()

before() // not restored yet, second sinon.stub is called? "Attempted to wrap ... which 
is already wrapped"

it()

after() // unwrap

after() // already restored, another error: "Restore is not a function"

The solution then was to create the stub within the Assertion block I needed it. something like this:

**File 1**

```
describe("First Stub", () => {
    let getTimestampStub;
    before(() => {});

    it("Should Stub getTimestamp before some code needs it", () => {
        getTimestampStub= sinon.stub(Utils, 'getTimestamp') .returns("SOME_TIMESTAMP");

        // Some code that in the process uses `Utils.getTimestamp`

        getTimestampStub.restore();
    });
    after(() => {});
});
```

**File 2**

```
describe("Second Stub", () => {
    let getTimestampStub;
    before(() => {});

    it("Should Stub getTimestamp before some code needs it", () => {
        getTimestampStub= sinon.stub(Utils, 'getTimestamp') .returns("SOME_TIMESTAMP");

        // Some code that in the process uses `Utils.getTimestamp`

        getTimestampStub.restore();
    });
    after(() => {});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeEach()` and `afterEach()` to replace `before()` and `after()` instead of moving the stub and restore calls into each individual `it()` block.

[What is the difference between `before()` and `beforeEach()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418580/what-is-the-difference-between-before-and-beforeeach)